# Is it kares to have relations during clean days but before she immerses in a mikvah?

Tags: halacha

Is it kares to have relations with her after her period ends but before she immerses in a mikvah?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.201.1?lang=bi